# Display the values in drop down priority wise

Tags: php, mysql

I have a drop down in which I have different locations, and depending upon this location drop down I have displayed Agents belonging to respective locations. Now I have allocated an agent to a location, so the agent which is allocated should be displayed last in the drop down. I am not getting how to do this. Please help.LIKE FIFO

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) Show us some code.

Answer (score 0):

One (not very efficient) way to do it, based on the absence of any of your code...

```
print "<select id="whatever">;
foreach ($arrAgents as $arrAgent) {
    if (empty($arrAgent['location'])) {
        printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $arrAgent['name'], $arrAgent['name']);
    }
}
foreach ($arrAgents as $arrAgent) {
    if (!empty($arrAgent['location'])) {
        printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $arrAgent['name'], $arrAgent['name']);
    }
}
print "</select>";
```

A better way to do it, assuming you're dealing with an array, is to sort your array based on the `location` element. This would probably require a user-defined sort, using [uasort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php).